# Force Floating Action Button to be on top of Keyboard

Tags: android, floating-action-button

I use the Android Studio Navigation Drawer Project with one MainActivity and multiple Fragments which are replacing the container inside my MainActivity.

Sometimes when I open my software keyboard the Floating action button appears above the keyboard and sometimes the keyboard covers the fab. Does somebody know why?

Comment: "on top" or "above"? "on top" means overlays, "above" means "north of the keyboard"

Comment: Why would you want the fab to be on top of the keyboard? That seems incredibly annoying for the users.

Comment: @WarrenFaith youre right. I mean above.

Comment: @BooleanCheese trust me. It is necessary ;)

Comment: Use coordinator layout... check the size of the keyboard and make that offset. Again, like others, that's a really bad UI/UX

Comment: But there is no other possibilty. If the keyboard covers the fab the User has to close the keyboard to confirm the input..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that somehow/sometimes your layout is not correctly changed. You should try to use `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` in your activity tag in the manifest.

That should resize the content to the size above the keyboard and therefore the FAB should be always above.

From a UX point of view: Maybe you change the "submit" functionality and move it from a FAB to the toolbar (like the gmail app does). So FAB for a "new" or "add" functionality and as soon as the user can provide input, you show a "send"/"submit" button in the toolbar.